# Replicated cache return value after expiration for long stored values(24hrs) ie. It never expires but works fine when expiry time is less (30 sec)

Tags: java, infinispan

I am using replicated cache with 3 node cluster. Entries are expiring for expiry time set to 30 sec but it does not when expiry time is 24 hrs.
Infinispan : 14.0.1
Java : jdk11

I am expecting the behaviour to be same for any expiry time provided.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.